# Excel VBA list all sheets in a specific file

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print a list of all the excel files under a specific folder. Along with the file names, I should also be able to print the names of all the sheets under the excel file.

Below is a sample of my code for printing the file names is as below. However, I am not able to figure out how to read the list of sheet names under the file?

```
    Sub ButtonRun_Excel_Compare_Report_Click()
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    ShowFolderList ("D:\temp")
End Sub

Sub ShowFolderList(folderspec)
    Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s, sFldr
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
    Set fc = f.SubFolders
     For Each f1 In fc
        If Right(f1, 1) <> "\" Then ShowFolderList f1 & "\" Else ShowFolderList f1
    Next
    Set fc = f.Files
    Rowcnt = 1
    For Each f1 In fc

        If f1.Name Like "*.xls" Then

            'How to loop through the Sheets under exach file?

            Sheet1.Cells(Rowcnt, 1) = f1.Name
            'Sheet1.Cells(Rowcnt, 2) = f1.Path
            Rowcnt = Rowcnt + 1
            'Debug.Print folderspec & f1.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: If you need to cater for all sheet types (including chart sheets) you'll have to open the workbook and loop through the sheets.

Comment: Use either [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358443/vba-list-of-sheets-hyperlinked) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654797/how-can-i-use-vba-to-list-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook-within-a-string) answer and wrap it in `Workbook.Open` and `.Close` commands.

Comment: If you don't want to open each excel workbook to get the sheet names you can use ADO and query the closed workbook. Example e.g. [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/47074-get-worksheet-names-closed-workbook.html).

Comment: @dee unofrtunately this example is very old and only works with .XLS files.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez good to know, thanks for this information!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to open the workbook and loop through the sheet objects

```
Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=folderspec & f1.Name
For i = 1 to ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    strFlenme = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    strShtNme = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Debug.print strFlenme & " - " & i & " '" & strShtNme & "'" 
Next
```